# Different names of sections

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, naming, sections-paragraphs

I wish to name my sections as "Exercise x - name" in the text but as "Exercise x" in the ToC and in the `\leftmark`. Does anyone have an idea for this? I have tried just manipulating my `\leftmark` by using `\thesection` instead. My problem here lies in, that I use the `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}` command so I don't have the section numbering.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a minimum working example (MWE) to show the basics of your problem and what you have tried that doesn't work.  (See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: I don't understand this question. Do you want the sections numbered or not? If not, what exactly is the problem? If so, why have you disabled the numbering? What *exactly* are you trying to do and how *exactly* are you trying to do it? As @cslstr said, show us the code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to use `\section[Exercise x]{Exercise x - name}`. The mandatory argument is used in the text, and the optional argument is used in the headings and the table of contents.

To make it easier to write you could define the command

> `\newcommand{\exercise}[2]{\section[Exercise #1]{Exercise #1 - #2}}`

and use it with `\exercise{x}{name}`, or, if all exercises are numbered continuously, you could use

> `\newcounter{Exercise}`
>   `\newcommand{\exercise}[1]{\stepcounter{Exercise}`
>       `\section[Exercise \arabic{Exercise}]{Exercise \arabic{Exercise} - #1}}`

to get automatic numbering.

Comment: And thanks to you too! You and Werner solved my problem. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you set `secnumdepth` to -1 to manually adjust the sectional naming. If you strategically update the three requirements (ToC/header/naming) *and* only use `\section` to represent your Exercises, then the following will suffice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{etoolbox,fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer    
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}% Page number in Right header
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}% \leftmark in Left header
\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}{#1}{Exercise #1}{}{}% Correct ToC
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{Exercise~\thesection}{}}% Header mark
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{Exercise \csname the#1\endcsname~--~}% Correct in-text \section # format
\let\oldsection\section% Store \section in \oldsection
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\oldsection[]{#1}}% Sections don't have a title in the ToC

\section{ABC}
\pagebreak

\section{DEF}
\pagebreak

\section{GHI}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! You have solved my problem (with Jonas Granholm)!